# Estimate hashrate from block info

Tags: proof-of-work, hashpower

Hi for POW is it possible to estimate hashrate for that block
using only available info from getblock [rpc](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblock.html) ( difficulty , timestamp, etc ) ?

Is there a correlation between difficulty and block found time ( this block - last block time )

Comment: is the calculation applicable for other POW such as ETH pre merge / ETC ?

Comment: You'd have to ask in a an ETH forum or Q&A website - people who answer questions in bitcoin.stackexchange.com mostly specialise in Bitcoin so other cryptocurrencies are treated as off-topic.